# socket.io | flask - 405 Method Not Allowed - Heroku

Tags: python, sockets, heroku, flask, socket.io

Get 405 Method Not Allowed when using/deploying a basic chat app on Heroku.
I'm currently testing WebSockets.

**Problem :**

- When sending a message, I got a 405 Method Not Allowed page
- When loading the main page, I got : Not allowed to request resource from the console (client side)
- When loading the main page, XMLHttpRequest cannot load from my url

There is the code base :

**Client side**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Flask_Chat_App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>No message yet..</h3>
    <div class="message_holder"></div>

    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
      <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Messages"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, { transport : ['websocket'] });
      console.log('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
      console.log("=>=>=> socket");
      console.log(socket);
      socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
          data: 'User Connected'
        } )
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
          let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
            user_name : user_name,
            message : user_input
          } )
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
      } )
      socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
        console.log( msg )
        if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
          $( 'h3' ).remove()
          $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
        }
      })
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**There is the python back-end (main.py):**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

There is the Procfile for Heroku :

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 main:app
```

There is the medium post I'm following : 
[link](https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d)

But there is no explanation about using socket in production.

Comment: Did you ever declare `document.domain` and such?

Comment: document.domain return the url of the page by default. I used console.log to check if it's correct, the url of the Heroku website come up. https://guarded-savannah-10162.herokuapp.com

Comment: this app is working locally and with the command line Heroku local.